# Laravel: customizing the model class

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I want to customize the Laravel's Model Class to log some other things (for example who created/updated/deleted that row in the DB.

I found this in the Model Class's 582-587

```
// First we need to create a fresh query instance and touch the creation and
// update timestamp on the model which are maintained by us for developer
// convenience. Then we will just continue saving the model instances.
if ($this->usesTimestamps()) {
    $this->updateTimestamps();
}
```

That uses this (Concerns/HasTimestamps.php 32-48):

```
/**
 * Update the creation and update timestamps.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function updateTimestamps()
{
    $time = $this->freshTimestamp();

    if (! $this->isDirty(static::UPDATED_AT)) {
        $this->setUpdatedAt($time);
    }

    if (! $this->exists && ! $this->isDirty(static::CREATED_AT)) {
        $this->setCreatedAt($time);
    }
}
```

My question: how to override this to also log the "who" without tinkering in the vendor folder? (The who comes from `Auth::user()->id`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called an `Observer`. It listens to database events for a model (like creating, deleting, updating ...).

Have a look into the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#observers).

Answer (score 0):

> how to override this to also log the "who" without tinkering in the vendor folder

You should create own base model class (usually `abstract` that would extend Eloquent's base class. Then put all you extra code in it and finally make all your models extend your base class instead.